# php switch code error

Tags: php, switch-statement

i having an error came out each time i echo this on my index.php

below is my switch code, as i'm using php dynamic site hence i use switch to change the data each time when different php is call.

```
<?php
function title_switch()
{
    $var = (isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home';
    switch ($var) {
        case 'home':
            $a['title']   = " &#187; Home";
            $a['meta_d']  = "This page is about my site!";
            $a['meta_k']  = "something, somethingelse";
            $a['slider1'] = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/jquery.easing.1.3.js\"></script>\n";
            $a['slider2'] = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/tms-0.3.js\"></script>\n";
            $a['slider3'] = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/tms_presets.js\"></script>\n";
            $a['main']    = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/script.js\"></script>\n";
            $a['pageid']  = "page1";
            $a['slider']  = "slide";
            break;
        case 'company':
            $a['title']  = " &#187; Company";
            $a['meta_d'] = "This page is about my site!";
            $a['meta_k'] = "something, somethingelse";
            $a['all']    = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/all.js\"></script>\n";
            $a['pageid'] = "page2";
            $a['slider'] = "banner";
            break;
        default:
            $a['title']  = " &#187; HTTP 404 - Page Not Found";
            $a['meta_d'] = "";
            $a['meta_k'] = "";
            break;
    }
    return $a;
}
$details = title_switch();
?>
```

this is my index.php on line 21

```
<?php echo $details['all']; ?>
```

if call home.php it will show below error

> Notice: Undefined index: all in C:\wamp\www\site\index.php on line 21
>   Call Stack
>
> ## Time    Memory  Function    Location
>
> 1 0.0035  258968  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0

if i call company.php it will not show any error...

may I know where did i went wrong? kinda confuse here...

example: if i call www.example.com/company it didnt show error, but if i call www.example.com it show error.

i wanted this code

```
<?php echo $details['all']; ?>
```

to show only if www.example.com/company and it will not show if www.example.com is call.

the code inside:

```
<?php echo $details['all']; ?>
```

is

```
case 'company':
        $a['title']  = " &#187; Company";
        $a['all']    = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/all.js\"></script>\n";
```

hope this can give a better clearer picture for everyone who can help me to solve the error.
thank you.

Comment: what is it in line 115?

Comment: `<?php echo $details['all']; ?>`
by the way, i wanted this code `<?php echo $details['all']; ?>` to trigger when only company.php is call, if home.php is call, then this code will not trigger...
i use the switch but it trigger no matter in home.php or company.php so that's why when i call home.php it show the error...
i really lost now where did i went wrong...

Comment: then tell us what is home.php and what is company.php. and what do you mean the 'code to trigger'? the variable either is defined or not.

Comment: `<?php echo $details['all']; ?>` is to trigger this code `$a['all']    = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/all.js\"></script>\n";` if page is home.php then the javascript no need to trigger, i only need this javascript for company.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$a['all']` is being set only when `switch($var)` is equal to `'company'`. You need to set it on every case.

Inside your switch you can set `$a['all']` to an empty value so PHP can at least find the index. A short example:

```
switch ($var) {
    case 'home':
        $a['all'] = '';
    case 'company':
        $a['all'] = '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/all.js\"></script>\n';
    default:
        $a['all'] = '';
}
```

Comment: means? i still abit blur here sorry :(

Comment: PHP outputs a notice when you try to access a key that does not exist. What he's saying is that your only setting `$a['all']` in one of your cases, so if another case is selected, `$a['all']` is undefined.

Comment: okie, i think i might get what he meant, but i don't want    `$a['all']` to trigger if home.php is call out, beside this switch i can't think anything else i could code. am still novice in php, any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: @Yvonnesecret You don't have to trigger it. I modified my answer to show you.

Comment: Baez, thanks!! it was so easy and i couldn't figure it out... such a shame on me.. once again thanks for your help! you saved my day from struggling in front of pc again and again...

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear what you are trying to do.
But define $a['all'] in the function even if it's empty. So, it will be set and not give a warning.
Add line $a['all'] = ''; in default:

Comment: this didn't help either...

Comment: First make sure that case 'company': is entered by an echo 'inside' there. If it does, the problem is probably in javascript then and you need to bebug that next.

Comment: the case 'company' is in there, `case 'company':
            $a['title']  = " &#187; Company";
            $a['meta_d'] = "This page is about my site!";
            $a['meta_k'] = "something, somethingelse";
            $a['all']    = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/all.js\"></script>\n";
            $a['pageid'] = "page2";
            $a['slider'] = "banner";
            break;`
i wanted case company to trigger the script else if home the script should be appear

Comment: then problem is in your javascript. use a debugger, like firebug of firefox to see what happens inside javascript, as it's impossible to figure out if it's entered and where it fails.

Comment: the javascript is correct, if i didnt use php and use <script> it show no error. however i revised again my question, hope the question give u a clearer picture where it go wrong

Comment: what you mean by provide /js/all.js? maybe you can take a look at my question again and see if you understand it.. thank you